# Can Excel retrieve data from Google Drive Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Can Excel retrieve data from a Google Spreadsheet? When I open Excel file.. some fields in it need information from a Google Excel spreadsheet.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is possible. You will need to write some code. .net can read and write both excel and google sheets data.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible to do this in a basic way without doing any programming:

- Ensure your Google Spreadsheet has been "Published to Web"
- In Excel, go to the Data tab and choose to create a new web query "From Web" − paste the link that would have been copied to your clipboard when you published Google's sheet

Your Google sheet will now appear inside Excel.

Answer (score 0):

First set the google sheet to "anyone with link can edit". Then download the google sheet as .xlsx. Copy the url of the download, paste it in Excel's get data from Web module. Tada!