# Can I get Excel to reach in with a lookup and grab data from a google sheet?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a mini P&L in Excel.  Some of the data is maintained in a large Google sheet.  I would like to do a lookup in Excel to find a customer and value in the Google sheet.  Is that possible?  Is that possible for someone who is good at Excel but not at all a programmer?

Comment: This is one approach: [Can Excel retrieve data from Google Drive Excel spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403907/can-excel-retrieve-data-from-google-drive-excel-spreadsheet)